# How to copy an attachment from an email to a case record using email service

Tags: attachment, csv, upload, apex-email-service, case-object

I'm Using an Email Service to create a custom object record and a case record. The email has an CSV attachment and have to attached to the case record.

Answer (score 1):

You could follow the example here http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/cookbook/Content/messaging_inbound_attachments.htm#messaging_inbound_attachments and do something very similar.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply ..Actually I already did this code but its not working on my part

Comment: In that case, can you add your code to the question and also add the error message that you are getting?